# Rendering an ASP.NET MVC view in a Razor layout refresh the whole site

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

In a ASP.Net MVC project, I'm using Razor built-in _layout.cshtml with a classic two columns layout with header and footer. The idea is to show my application views in the right column of the layout and have a consistent look for the whole site without duplicating code...

The problem is that each time I call a view and have it content rendered in my layout right column with  @RenderBody(), the whole layout is refreshed. Is it normal behaviour?

Is there any built-in mecanism in this Razor's layout concept to refresh only the rendered view content and not the whole site or do I have to make a jQuery Ajax call and make a div replacement with view content?

Thanks

Etienne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to switch your content dinamically, you have to load data via ajax and then replace the right column of your site...Razor don't have a "automatic mode" to do that. =P

I have some projects using this 'approach'. I render my views as partials views (in controller) and then I get the html and put where I want.

Comment: Is it me or this make this whole layout thing a little useless for people like me that try to not waste resource uselessly?

Comment: The point of the layout is the same as the point of a master page - to keep you from needing to cut and paste elements that are present on multiple pages.

Answer (score 0):

**u can use iframe instead of @RenderBody() while calling that page @{ Layout = null;}**

```
    <ul>
        <li class="LoadContent" data-url="http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/">Jquery-not-selector</li>
        <li class="LoadContent" data-url="http://api.jquery.com/contents/">Jquery-contents</li>
    </ul>
    <iframe src="" width="80%" height="600" id='frameDemo'></iframe> ​


  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.LoadContent').click(function () {
             $('#frameDemo').attr('src', $(this).data('url'));
        });
    });​
```

for [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/XbRzF/)

Comment: for u url also need to change?

Answer (score 0):

MVC has a built-in ajax mechanism you can use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505086(v=vs.108).aspx

In my experience, it's only really useful for very simple things; I usually just end up using $.post().

Comment: Agree! This ends up holding you.